# Do multiple rounds of tree (GBR) param tuning lead to overoptimistic CV scores?

Tags: machine-learning, random-forest, scikit-learn, boosting

I see suggestions like [this](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2016/02/complete-guide-parameter-tuning-gradient-boosting-gbm-python/) for tuning a GradientBoostingRegressor's params through multiple steps. In each step, the best params are selected via CV. For example (abbreviated steps):

1. find some of the best tree-based params through grid search
2. find the remaining best tree-based params through grid search, having fixed other params in step 1
3. decrease the learning rate and increase n_estimators

My question is whether this method of choosing the best hyperparams through multiple passes leads to overfitting or a cross-validation score that is overoptimistic in tree-based models like RandomForestRegressor or GradientBoostingRegressor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No, you don't over-fit**

The method you chose to tune your parameters is *independent* of whether your performance estimation is biased (over-estimated) or not.

As long as you use CV for your parameter-tuning, you **cannot** "over-fit" in general (meaning to create a too complex model) but only be "over-precise" (like deciding whether using 319 or 318 trees is the best...) which, apart from consuming time, does not really harm you.

Edit: just to mention, if you do have small data-sets, really at the lower limit of what you feel comfortable, you can "overfit" to some extend. Simple tip: if you are using any boosting algorithms, don't go for the last 1 percent of the score; if you use any other algorithm, let the L2-regularization (or other, similar regularization) better be a little higher then the "optimum".

Beside: the site you mentioned has some good tips, mostly the one with the n_estimators/learning_rate ratio that can be increased in the end (only!).

(*Remark: In very special cases, where you know that your training data is quite different from what you will predict on, pure CV-based optimization is not sufficient but there needs to be extended, problem specific tuning*)

Comment: In addition to the question of overfitting, I was also curious about evaluating model performance - it appears that the entire model building process would need to be repeated to actually estimate performance accurately, which is not computationally practical using this procedure

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "model building process"? And what do you mean by "estimate performance"? Do you want to use a holdout set to estimate the performance? There are several ways to "estimate performance";)

Comment: Suppose you then use params tuned using this approach to then estimate performance of a GBR using K-fold CV. The hyperparams selected have been chosen using multiple passes through the dataset, in contrast to the more common K-fold CV pipeline that selects hyperparams inside each fold.

Comment: There is the possibility to make a holdout set: you don't use all of the data for your cv-optimization but instead predict in the end on that holdout set (which is somehow a more reliable measure for how well your algorithm does as this set has not yet been involved into the hyper-optimization). If you have small data-sets in general, you can use this approach (as CV on the whole data can *slightly* over-fit). But you best read about the holdout-set strategy. And yes, I agree, if you want to do this K-folded as well, you have a huge computation time...